# Why upload servlet returns access is denied error

Tags: java, jsp

I am writing a jsp file that contains register new user form. The form include upload file type. There is a servlet that handle the form. The servlet upload the file to local directory folder, and also upload the user detail to database. However, the servlet returns access is denied error. I've set all permission to the Java and the folder. Please help me guys. I stared at this very code for half a day still couldn't find the error. It returns:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:locationURL access is denied.

servlet

```
package net.codejava.upload;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.util.List;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import readConfig.readConfig;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

@WebServlet("/uploadServlet")
@MultipartConfig(maxFileSize = 16177215)    // upload file's size up to 16MB
public class FileUploadDBServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int MEMORY_THRESHOLD   = 1024 * 1024 * 3;  // 3MB
    private static final int MAX_FILE_SIZE      = 1024 * 1024 * 40; // 40MB
    private static final int MAX_REQUEST_SIZE   = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50MB

    // database connection setting
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String fileName ="";
        String dbPath= readConfig.getProperties("filePath");
        // checks if the request actually contains upload file
            if (!ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
                // if not, we stop here
                PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
                writer.println("Error: Form must has enctype=multipart/form-data.");
                writer.flush();
                return;
            }

            // configures upload settings
            DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            // sets memory threshold - beyond which files are stored in disk 
            factory.setSizeThreshold(MEMORY_THRESHOLD);
            // sets temporary location to store files
            factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

            ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

            // sets maximum size of upload file
            upload.setFileSizeMax(MAX_FILE_SIZE);

            // sets maximum size of request (include file + form data)
            upload.setSizeMax(MAX_REQUEST_SIZE);

            // constructs the directory path to store upload file
            // this path is relative to application's directory
            String uploadPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("")
                    + File.separator + dbPath;

            // creates the directory if it does not exist
            File uploadDir = new File(uploadPath);
            if (!uploadDir.exists()) {
                uploadDir.mkdir();
            }

            try {
                // parses the request's content to extract file data
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

                if (formItems != null && formItems.size() > 0) {
                    // iterates over form's fields
                    for (FileItem item : formItems) {
                        // processes only fields that are not form fields
                        if (!item.isFormField()) {
                            fileName = new File(item.getName()).getName();
                            String filePath = uploadPath + File.separator + fileName;
                            File storeFile = new File(filePath);

                            // saves the file on disk
                            item.write(storeFile);
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                request.setAttribute("message",
                        "There was an error: " + ex.getMessage());
            }
        // gets values of text fields
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        String dbURL = readConfig.getProperties("conUrl");
        String dbUser = readConfig.getProperties("dbUser");
        String dbPass = readConfig.getProperties("dbUser");


        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
        String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client

        try {
            // connects to the database
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

            // constructs SQL statement
            String sql = "INSERT INTO ssl_user (name, password,email,file) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setString(1, name);
            statement.setString(2, password);
            statement.setString(3, email);
            statement.setString(4, fileName);

            // sends the statement to the database server
            int row = statement.executeUpdate();
            if (row > 0) {
                message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                // closes the database connection
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // sets the message in request scope
            request.setAttribute("Message", message);

            // forwards to the message page
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

logs:

```
savepath:-----C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\apache-tomcat-8.0.50\wtpwebapps\registration\upload
Mar 15, 2018 12:08:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [net.codejava.upload.FileUploadDBServlet] in context with path [/registration] threw exception
java.io.IOException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\apache-tomcat-8.0.50\wtpwebapps\registration\upload (Access is denied)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.write(ApplicationPart.java:122)
at net.codejava.upload.FileUploadDBServlet.doPost(FileUploadDBServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\HP\Downloads\Compressed\apache-tomcat-8.0.50\wtpwebapps\registration\upload (Access is denied)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.write(DiskFileItem.java:400)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.write(ApplicationPart.java:120)
... 23 more
```

Comment: Share full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: @SandeepRandhawa i've updated my post\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Your code does not have permissions to write into the `C Drive`. The simple solution for you right now is to close your IDE and then `Run it as administrator` or just set permissions for it.
I hope it helps and let me know if that was the case.